# The inverse image of an open cover

Tags: general-topology

I have been reading the proof of a continuous function mapping compact sets to compact sets.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous and onto where $X$ is compact. Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ be an open cover of $Y$. Then $\{f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha}$ covers X.

Why is it true that$\{f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha}$ covers X?

Couldn't there be $x\in X$ such that $x \notin \{f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$?

Comment: For $x \in X$, $f(x) \in U_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. Then $x \in f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. No problem.

Suppose $x \in X$, then because $x$ lies in the domain of the function $f$, $f(x)$ is defined and in fact (by definition) $f(x) \in Y$.

Now since $U_\alpha$'s cover $Y$, there exists some $\alpha$ such that $f(x) \in U_\alpha$. Thus $x \in f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$.

Comment: Notice that you don't even need to assume $f$ is onto! [All that $f$ being onto guarantees is that the inverse images aren't empty.]

Comment: So let's say that $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Now let $U$ be an open neighborhood around $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then it is true that $x_1,x_2 \in f^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: Yes. Suppose $f(x_1)=y=f(x_2) \in U$. Then $x_1$ and $x_2$ belong to $f^{-1}(\{y\}) \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ (and possibly many many other $x$'s as well). For example: $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Then $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{\dots,-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi,2\pi,\dots \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Select $x \in X$. Then $x$ is in the domain of $f$. This means there is a $y \in Y$ with $f(x) = y$. Since $\{ U_{\alpha} \} $ is an open cover of $Y$. For some $\alpha$ we have $y \in U_{\alpha}$. But then $x \in f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$.